# Path to project in the web container is different from path on host

Tags: drupal, ddev

Just came to ddev from full virtual machines and love it. Thanks for developing such a great tool:-)

Setup is ddev on WSL, Ubuntu on top. Drupal 8 and 9.

I am now having weird issues with private files in Drupal9. After some debugging I discovered the following:

PHP realpath() returns:

'/home/name/' for realpath('/home/name')

**false** for realpath('/home/name/drupal9')

the same for any other directory like /home/name/xxx.

I have no idea where to start to fix this.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks
Christophe

Comment: The path in the web container would be something like `/var/www/html/drupal9` (or just `/var/www/html` if that is where your project root is). You can check out the environment with `ddev ssh` to see how "your" system looks like for ddev sites.

Comment: @JonasEberle Many thanks, you solved my problem:-)

Comment: Additional note: 'ddev drush status' will list all the different pathes just fine.

Comment: 2nd additional note: with 'ddev ssh' one can ssh into the server container. There you can inspect the full run-time installation.

Answer (score 1):

DDEV-Local uses docker, and you can think of docker containers as separate machines with separately named filesystems.

So your project inside the web container is always mounted at /var/www/html. Even though your code may be at /home/name/something on the host (in WSL2 in this case), it's /var/www/html inside the container. So probably you need to use realpath() on something that's inside the project, as Jonas Eberle points out in the comments.

I hope that helps. If it doesn't, let's continue the conversation.

Comment: Hello Randy

Jonas' and your comments helped me find the right path. It's /var/www/html/web for the root of a Drupal Composer installation. Excellent, thank you very much.

Thanks for a great project, It blows my mind :-)